# How do print exactly X digits in hex

Tags: c, c89, ansi-c

I have an integer, want to print exactly 6 digits of hex.

I tried

```
fprintf(stdout,"%06x\n",number);
```

it does work perfectly when the MSBs are 0, but I use 2's completment for negative numbers, and it doesn't work for them

for example. here is what it prints

`ffffff9f` negative number, 8 digits.

`0b680c` - positive number, OK, 6 digits.

my numbers would never be too large to fit in 24bits, so they should always fit in 6 hexadecimal characters, but how do I make it, so it will trim the left part to always print exactly 6 digits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert the number to `unsigned long`, as a side-effect this will *ensure 2's complement representation* even if the target used some other representation for signed negative numbers; then mask with `0xFFFFFF`. I.e.

```
fprintf(stdout,"%06lx\n", (unsigned long)number & 0xFFFFFFUL);
```

which is guaranteed to be maximally portable; i.e. work on targets that has 16-bit ints, different representations for negative numbers etc. (I believe the outer cast to unsigned long is not necessary because `0xFFFFFF` should be